# Changing Form Label value from a separate Class file C#

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to change information in a form label from a separate class file but I do not understand why it is not working, I have verified that the file is being read but nothing changes.

```
        private void frmBattleArea_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (frmSinglePlayerCharacterSelection.america == true)
        {
            america = true;
            America.InitialAmerica();
        }
```

This is where the file is being called.

```
class America{
        static public void InitialAmerica()
    {
       // frmBattle.lblP1Name.Text = "United States";
        Properties.Settings.Default.lhead = "United States";
        frmBattle.lblP1Name.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.lhead;
    }
}
```

And this is my class file. I originally had the Properties.Settings... as a String variable which is what I would prefer. Any help would be fantastic! Thanks guys!

Comment: How does the `America` class know what `frmBattle` is?

Comment: Add frmBattle.Show() so you can see it.  Probably not what you want, so tell the class what *specific* form object needs to be updated.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I initialized it in the top. frmBattlearea frmBattle = new frmBatleArea(); of the class

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean?

Comment: Use the form object you are actually looking at.  Using `new frmBatleArea()` in your class is never correct since it creates a new form object.  That isn't visible because you never called its Show() method.  Pass the object reference through the class constructor.

Comment: But when I am calling this class, the form is still visible so I am not understanding what you are meaning @HansPassant

Comment: Winforms is relentlessly OOPy, hard to write good code when that's still opaque.  Golden rule to use whenever you contemplate writing `new SomeForm` is to consider whether you truly meant to create a new window.  You didn't here, you want to use the existing window.  So your class needs the object reference to that existing window.

Comment: Ah I understand now @HansPassant , thank you very much!

Comment: @HansPassant is there a way I can do a process where I am not reopening the form? I tried this.Refresh(); but it does not do the effect I thought would happen